# Offline - Installable Software on the image?

Tags: usb, package-management, software-center, offline

I made installed Ubuntu 16.04.01 via a bootable USB Stick from a downloaded Ubuntu *.iso made with the unetbootin.exe tool in windows. It installed great to a computer with no internet access. worked like a charm!

When I opened the Ubuntu Software center I expected to see installed and not installed software to browse. But I only did see installed software and no other.
I tried to install aptitude in the command line, to see if I missed some settings in the gui, but I got this:

```
>su apt-get install aptitude
Building depencency tree
Reading state information..done
[.....]
E: Package 'aptitude' has no installation candidate
```

I also tried to add the USB repository explicitly in SoftwareCenter/Software&Updates/Other Software/Add.. by adding

```
deb file:///media/<username>/ubuntustick/dists xenial main restricted
```

The Software center did not show more programs nor did I get other output from the command line install. I am out of ideas.

So I guess my Question is:
On the standard Installation ISO files, is there any other package than the ones installed by default?

I did read the installation notes and it said "server and desktop share the same repositories". So at least I would have expected to find some server software on the cd image. So I would rather expect I missed a switch or something.

edit: repository updating with the ISO repository on USB gave the following
output. I added

```
deb file:///media/CatMan/UBUNTU1640 xenial main restricted
```

Output was:

```
Get:1 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial InRelease
Ign:1 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial InRelease
Get:2 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial Release [3.355 B]
Err:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Get:2 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial Release [3.355 B]
Get:6 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:6 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:7 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial/main amd64 Packages
Get:8 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:8 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Get:7 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial/main amd64 Packages [9.558 B]
Get:8 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [1.851 B]
Ign:7 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial/main amd64 Packages
Get:7 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial/main amd64 Packages [27,9 kB]
Err:7 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial/main amd64 Packages
  File not found - /media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages (2: No such file or directory)
Ign:8 file:/media/CatMan/UBUNTU16401 xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Reading package lists...
```

Comment: It sounds like you have gone as far as you can off-line.Anything that does not show up in the installed programs part of the software center is downloadable online.A wired internet connection is best,as you will need to do updates to get everything working correctly.

Comment: @bob. Thanks for your remark. Actually i did use that sucessfully on some computers and found it very convenient, indeed. Its quite surprising that with everything else so simple its seemingly so complex to install software from non-dvd installation media though the software center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the standard ISO, there are only a few installable packages, mostly related to drivers:

```
/pool
├── main
│   ├── b
│   │   └── b43-fwcutter
│   │       └── b43-fwcutter_019-2_amd64.deb
│   ├── d
│   │   └── dkms
│   │       └── dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11_all.deb
│   ├── g
│   │   ├── glibc
│   │   │   └── libc6-i386_2.23-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
│   │   ├── grub
│   │   │   └── grub_0.97-29ubuntu68_amd64.deb
│   │   ├── grub2
│   │   │   ├── grub-efi-amd64-bin_2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3_amd64.deb
│   │   │   ├── grub-efi-amd64_2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3_amd64.deb
│   │   │   └── grub-efi_2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3_amd64.deb
│   │   └── grub2-signed
│   │       └── grub-efi-amd64-signed_1.66+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3_amd64.deb
│   ├── l
│   │   └── lupin
│   │       └── lupin-support_0.57_amd64.deb
│   ├── m
│   │   └── mouseemu
│   │       └── mouseemu_0.16-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb
│   ├── s
│   │   ├── setserial
│   │   │   └── setserial_2.17-49_amd64.deb
│   │   ├── shim
│   │   │   └── shim_0.8-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
│   │   └── shim-signed
│   │       └── shim-signed_1.12+0.8-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
│   ├── u
│   │   ├── ubiquity
│   │   │   ├── oem-config-gtk_2.21.63_all.deb
│   │   │   └── oem-config_2.21.63_all.deb
│   │   ├── ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu
│   │   │   └── oem-config-slideshow-ubuntu_113_all.deb
│   │   └── user-setup
│   │       └── user-setup_1.63ubuntu4_all.deb
│   └── w
│       ├── wvdial
│       │   └── wvdial_1.61-4.1_amd64.deb
│       └── wvstreams
│           ├── libuniconf4.6_4.6.1-7_amd64.deb
│           ├── libwvstreams4.6-base_4.6.1-7_amd64.deb
│           └── libwvstreams4.6-extras_4.6.1-7_amd64.deb
└── restricted
    ├── b
    │   └── bcmwl
    │       └── bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb
    └── i
        ├── intel-microcode
        │   └── intel-microcode_3.20151106.1_amd64.deb
        └── iucode-tool
            └── iucode-tool_1.5.1-1_amd64.deb

31 directories, 24 files
```

IIRC, aside from language packs and the installer itself, the only additional software that the *live* environment has is GParted.

Yes, the server and various desktop flavours share the same repositories, but the ISOs are focused and don't contain more stuff than they need.

Also, when adding a local repository, note that the path you specified should contain both the `dists` and `pool` directories, and not actually be one of those:

```
deb file:///media/<username>/ubuntustick/ xenial main restricted
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply. It seems I did, indeed, miss something, since my Software center does not list the GParted. Your post is the first I see that mentions the pool directories, also the etc

Comment: @CatMan as I said, GParted is in the **live** environment, not in the extra packages.

Comment: Sorry, too slow editing the broken comment above. Thanks for your fast reply. It seems I missed something. I do understand that the Internet repositories of server and desktop are the same, but the CD/ISO repositories are not? I guess I misinterpreted the installation documentation. Does that mean, consequently, that if I prepared an USB stick again from the server *.iso I would be offered additional software in the software center?  I am confused about GParted. I would like to understand what I missed to set up the USB as repository. I can not enter 2 lines, like pool and dists...??!?

Comment: @CatMan if you used the server ISO, you'd be in a worse situation, since it doesn't have a GUI environment available for installation from the ISO. For setting up the repository, you specify a place where apt can find a dists and a pool directory. So you specify one line, which has the path to the parent directory. Not that setting up a repository for the ISO is going to do you any good here.

Comment: Sorry for the fuss, I did not spot your change to the line immediately. Now I did remove the "dists" from the repository line, I hope that was what should include "dists" and "pool". It did not complain, but I still can not see any package in software center. I tries to search for those you had in that fancy list like "shim", "dkms", "setserial", but it always said "No Application Found".

Comment: @CatMan in a terminal, try `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install dkms`

Comment: I did not meant to re-install with the server iso, I just meant to plug in that USB stick and hope software center would then show me other programs. I did see a lot of posts about offline, so I know I am not the only one, but all were wanting to set up a special repository. Thats far beyond what I want to do now, since my trials in that direction ended up nowhere. Now I just need the most simple step and work with a 100% OK repository. That should include the ones on the ISO, right?. When I get those working I will learn to to it from the command line and expand from there.

Comment: You are answering faster than I could think, whow. I just tried the update and dkms install. install said "E: Unable to locate package dkms". So is dkms a package that is part of the desktop iso?

Comment: @CatMan please edit your post to include the output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: I added output to the main post.

Comment: I am checking your post as an answer, since the actual question was about what was on the ISO. From your post I saw that even without working software center I can see in /pool/main and /pool/restricted the actual packages on the ISO. All other posts I have seen so far all referred to the /dists/*.* directory where you can not get that information without additional command line skills. However, I still do not understand why the system does not work, but I think it is better to have a separate post on that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @CatMan Alright. I'll check the `apt update` problem later, when I can setup a VM to test it. The error is surprising, since `apt` seems to able to get `restricted` but not `main` repository information