# Native Windows Terminal access to Ubuntu PC?

Tags: command-line, windows, remote

How do I connect from a Win7 PC via local LAN to a Ubuntu Dektop 16.04.01 PC's command line window using only software that comes on the original installation DVDs?

Edit: Did a Full rephrase of the question, because answers so far showed that the question was not understood as I intended. This is *not* about anything I can download from the web an put to these machines somehow, e.g. SSH or anything. There are enough other answers that address those as linked in the first answer. So its not a duplicate.
Its about can I achieve it with what is on the original DVD only. As its an ubuntu forum, answers may skip the windows side, of course.

Comment: @Fabby might be a problem given their other question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/872193/offline-installable-software-on-the-image. But if OP has a different PC connected to the internet, they could use http://askubuntu.com/q/974/158442

Comment: @muru The difference between a mod and a worm like me...

Comment: @muru good point, but related only by chance. 
I have seen the link about to keryx before and checked it out. As it is written in that post, development is ceased and for a newbie there is not much left to get started with it.

Comment: @CatMan there are number of other answers there that you can try. Never stop at the top answer

Comment: @muru, you mean the keryx post? Sorry. I'll check it again.

Comment: @muru, Was a good point, thanks. Thats a long post with a lot of stuff. Most involve linux commands via internet, so not applicable, but I found down in answer 15 an offline repository approach thats using a still active tool. Even a very user friendly a pdf description! It'll help to get offline linux setups working. Hoever I did not see a solution for this post. This is about access to a remote machine of unknown configuration (except distribution) with no installation option.

Comment: Then you find a third system with internet access. You didn't get the Ubuntu ISO from thin air, did you?

Comment: @muru, currently yes I have acess to a windows pc with internet. Please do not mix my other post with this one. This one is about a specific use case which is very typical (at least for me) in offline scenarios. I just want to learn about Ubuntu what I can do with it and what not. I am fine, if there is no other way than post install ssh. Its just that this rules out using ubuntu where those use cases can (and will) happen. 
It would be sad to not use linux by overlooking features that are there but I just do not know about. Does that make sense?

Comment: @CatMan I'm not mixing anything. Fact of the matter is, unless you have some ways to get packages to the system, then what you can do with is limited. You want SSH. Somebody else wants image processing. A third user will want yet another set of software. There's no pleasing everyone, is there? Anyway, this is not the place for that discussion. If you want to make a feature request, do so by all means. But not here.

Comment: @muru. Sorry I did not want to make you upset. If you re-read my question I do not want ssh, or anything. I am looking for an answer from experts better than me (not difficult :-). The answer I got so far did not fit the question. Maybe the answer is no, but finding that out is the point of posting a question, right?

Comment: @CatMan if you won't install SSH, then the answer is essentially no.

Comment: @muru, thats bad news. If you want to copy that into an answer, I will vote that as the answer to that question.

Comment: System does not allow me any more to put in an answer myself, so I put it into the comment.  There is NO way to get remote into a fresh Desktop install from Win7. There is a possible detour: Install the server from the server CD. That has OpenSSH in its repositories and can be accessed out of the box from Window7, e.g. via the PuTTY tool. If the remote stuff is done and access a repository (internet or local with apt-mirror) is available the full desktop can be installed at any time by 'sudo tasksel'. In tasksel there is the choice between Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu etc.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51925/how-do-i-configure-a-new-ubuntu-installation-to-accept-ssh-connections) to install a secure shell on the Ubuntu machine and install an `ssh` client on the Windows machine.  (Windows solutions are off-topic here on Ask Ubuntu but not [over here](http://superuser.com))

Comment: Using ssh according to the post is not standard ubuntu desktop. I tried to install it as described in that lined post and it did not find the packet. 
Isn't there another way?

Comment: No, you need Internet access to install from online repositories. You can however google the package from another PC) , download it to removable media and install it on the offline machine.

Comment: Nope.  Pick up the machine, go to a friend who has an Internet connection and install it there or download the entire [Ubuntu mirror](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors#Releases_Statistics) for your release and dump it on a hard disk and install from there.